# VGA Monitor Selector Switch

Tags: multiple-monitors, vga, kvm-switch

I find myself in a strange situation trying to replace an old piece of hardware. My old VGA switch is becoming buggy, so I decided to buy a replacement, only to find that I cannot locate the correct device anywhere on the Internet. Perhaps I am just not searching for the right word...

I am talking about a VGA switch that takes 1 output from PC, and sends it to 1 of N VGA monitors connected to the switch. There is a selector on the front that selects a specific monitor. All I can find now are the switches that go the other way around - N PCs to 1 VGA, or VGA Multipliers that send the same signal to N monitors simultaneously.

The ability to connect only one specific monitor at a time gives me the ability to detect the correct resolution and model settings of the hooked up monitor and change the output signal accordingly. I don't understand how this would work with a multiplier, if the different hooked up monitors are vastly different in their sizes and capabilities. Is there some logic in the multiplier which would announce itself as a monitor with all possible resolutions, and I get to pick the one I want at any given time? If so, that would probably work, although these things are powered, which is annoying.

Or maybe the switches that say that they support N PCs to 1 VGA can be just used in reverse? I guess that would work if the switch makes a very simple point-to-point connection between the ports...

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: I would think a KVM but reversed should work. Do you have one to try out ?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not. I am waiting to hear from someone who tried it before I buy.

Comment: I'll give it a shot when I have some time. I should have a spare KVM sometime soon.